# How to implement a lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda

If I've class, for example

```
class A
{
    A(int size,std::function????){};
}
```

How do I make use of lambda function for initialisation in constructor

```
A a(5,[](){});
```

example of initilsation like

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    a[i]=3*i;
```

Comment: Hint: study what `std::function`'s template parameter is, and how it relates to a function's signature. Then figure out what your lambda's signature is, and construct the appropriate template parameter.

Comment: This is not clear.  What do you want the lambda to actually do?  What's the relation of the for loop to the rest of the code?

Comment: to set the data values of A to any function returns;example a[i]=i^2; or a[i]=1^3

Answer (score 1):

Make the constructor a *template*:

```
class A
{
public:
    template <typename F>
    A(int size, F f) {}
};
```